# mktime shows inconsistent output

Tags: c, time, mktime

While trying to write code which returns 24 hours less than a given time, `mktime()`shows inconsistent output. I calculate it similar to this: `current_time(GMT) - 86400` which should return the right value. All we need to do is calculate based on the input time; we used `mktime()` to change the time and get the GMT time and then do the regular calculation. I included my code below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main()
{
    time_t currentTime, tempTime;
    struct tm *localTime;

    time(&currentTime);
    //localTime = localtime(&currentTime);
    localTime = gmtime(&currentTime); //get the time in GMT as we are in PDT

    printf("Time %2d:%02d\n", (localTime->tm_hour)%24, localTime->tm_min);
    localTime->tm_hour = 19; // Set the time to 19:00 GMT
    localTime->tm_min = 0;
    localTime->tm_sec = 0;
    tempTime = mktime(localTime);
    //tempTime = mktime(localTime) - timezone;

    printf("Current time is %ld and day before time is %ld\n", currentTime, (currentTime - 86400));
    printf("Current timezone is %ld \n", timezone);

    printf("New time is %ld and day before time is %ld\n",tempTime, (tempTime - 86400));
}
```

But when we check the output it is coming back incorrect after the call to call `mktime()`. Below is the output of above program.

```
$ ./a.out
Time 11:51
Current time is 1341229916 and day before time is 1341143516
New time is 1341284400 and day before time is 1341198000
$ ./print_gmt 1341229916
Mon Jul  2 11:51:56 2012
$ ./print_gmt 1341143516
Sun Jul  1 11:51:56 2012
$ ./print_gmt 1341284400
Tue Jul  3 03:00:00 2012
$ ./print_gmt 1341198000
Mon Jul  2 03:00:00 2012
$ date
Mon Jul  2 04:52:46 PDT 2012
```

Now if we un-comment the line which subtracts the timezone (present in time.h), then the output is as expected. Below is the value for timezone in above program

```
$ ./a.out
. . .
Current timezone is 28800
. . .
```

So why is there such inconsistent behavior for `mktime()` although the man pages do not mention such adjustment of the timezone.
Is there something we are missing while doing such conversions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where does `timezone` come froim?

Comment: `mktime()` assumes local time as input not UTC (aka GMT). So it adds a time shift if not located in Greenwich.

Comment: @alk, `timezone` is part of the _X/Open System Interfaces Extension_ and is defined as `extern long timezone;` in `time.h`.

Comment: @HristoIliev Oops, yes .. - thanks for pointing me to this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is here:

[`The mktime() function shall convert the broken-down time, expressed as local time, in the structure pointed to by timeptr, into a time since the Epoch value...`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/functions/mktime.html)

Note the words `local time`. The C standard has them too in the description of `mktime()`:

`The mktime function converts the broken-down time, expressed as local time, in the
structure pointed to by timeptr into a calendar time value with the same encoding as
that of the values returned by the time function.`

`gmtime()`, on the other hand, produces time in GMT/UTC and not in your time zone:

[`The gmtime() function shall convert the time in seconds since the Epoch pointed to by timer into a broken-down time, expressed as Coordinated Universal Time (UTC).`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/functions/gmtime.html)

**EDIT**: If you just want 19:00 of the previous GMT/UTC day, you can do this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(void)
{
    time_t currentTime;
    struct tm *brokenDownTime;

    time(&currentTime);

    // get the time in GMT as we are in PDT
    brokenDownTime = gmtime(&currentTime);
    printf("Current Time (GMT): %2d:%02d\n"
           "  seconds since Epoch: %ld\n", 
           brokenDownTime->tm_hour,
           brokenDownTime->tm_min,
           (long)currentTime);

    // "Unwind" time to 0:00:00 (assuming time_t is an integer):
    currentTime /= 24 * (time_t)3600;
    currentTime *= 24 * (time_t)3600;

    brokenDownTime = gmtime(&currentTime);
    printf("Time at the beginning of the current GMT day: %2d:%02d\n"
           "  seconds since Epoch: %ld\n", 
           brokenDownTime->tm_hour,
           brokenDownTime->tm_min,
           (long)currentTime);

    // Add 19 hours:
    currentTime += 19 * (time_t)3600;

    brokenDownTime = gmtime(&currentTime);
    printf("Time at 19:00:00 of the current GMT day: %2d:%02d\n"
           "  seconds since Epoch: %ld\n", 
           brokenDownTime->tm_hour,
           brokenDownTime->tm_min,
           (long)currentTime);

    // Subtract 1 day:
    currentTime -= 24 * (time_t)3600;

    brokenDownTime = gmtime(&currentTime);
    printf("Time at 19:00:00 of the previous GMT day: %2d:%02d\n"
           "  seconds since Epoch: %ld\n", 
           brokenDownTime->tm_hour,
           brokenDownTime->tm_min,
           (long)currentTime);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Current Time (GMT): 13:23
  seconds since Epoch: 1341235429
Time at the beginning of the current GMT day:  0:00
  seconds since Epoch: 1341187200
Time at 19:00:00 of the current GMT day: 19:00
  seconds since Epoch: 1341255600
Time at 19:00:00 of the previous GMT day: 19:00
  seconds since Epoch: 1341169200
```

Comment: Actually I was using the code using localtime() but as we need to do the calculation on GMT time and not on current system time as the solution runs in different timezone I was thinking that mktime can take GMT time as input and then do the conversions.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't state whether you're working on a POSIX(-like) target or some oddball system, but in the former case, you can just use the POSIX formula to convert broken down time to `time_t`:

```
tm_sec + tm_min*60 + tm_hour*3600 + tm_yday*86400 +
    (tm_year-70)*31536000 + ((tm_year-69)/4)*86400 -
    ((tm_year-1)/100)*86400 + ((tm_year+299)/400)*86400
```

Source: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap04.html#tag_04_15

Answer (score 1):

`mktime(3)` uses *current* timezone to perform the conversion. This is somewhat cryptically written in [the standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904875/functions/mktime.html):

> Local timezone information shall be set as though `mktime()` called `tzset()`.

Answer (score 1):

The [mktime specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/mktime.html) states that its argument represents “broken-down time, **expressed as local time**”. So anything you pass to mktime has to be in local time, not GMT. Your variable `localTime` has `local` in its name, but was in fact obtained from `gmtime`, so its result describes the curretn time **in GMT**. Passing that to `mktime` is inconsistent.

Answer (score 0):

On some systems there is also a [timegm](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/timegm.3.html) function which should do the right thing.
I've just checked on Linux and it produces the correct value (e.g. timegm (gmtime (time)) == time).

[Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22557778/257568) how to use it in Windows.
And here's a [similar answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4682556/257568).