# C++ mktime and DST

Tags: c++, mktime

I am processing stored dates and times. I store them in a file in GMT in a string format
(i.e. `DDMMYYYYHHMMSS`). When a client queries, I convert this string to a `struct tm`, then convert it to seconds using `mktime`. I do this to check for invalid DateTime. Again I do convert seconds to string format. All these processing is fine, no issues at all.

But I have one weird issue: I stored the date and time in GMT with locale also GMT. Because of day light saving, my locale time changed to GMT+1. Now, if I query the stored date and time I get 1 hour less because the `mktime` function uses locale, i.e. GMT+1, to convert the `struct tm` to seconds (`tm_isdst` set to -1 so `mktime` detects daylight savings etc. automatically).

Any ideas how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 8):

Use [`_mkgmtime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2093ets1.aspx)/[`timegm`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/timegm) as a complement to `mktime`.

```
time_t mkgmtime(struct tm* tm)
{
#if defined(_WIN32)
   return _mkgmtime(tm);
#elif defined(linux)
   return timegm(tm);
#endif
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this might solve the problem. As of now every where mktime has been used for date operations but I will have to add new function to use mkgmtime for this specific purpose.

Answer (score 1):

> The Daylight Saving Time flag (tm_isdst) is greater than zero if Daylight Saving Time is in effect, zero if Daylight Saving Time is not in effect, and less than zero if the information is not available.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/tm/

Comment: My program will be used in different parts of the world, that's why tm_isdst set to -1 so mktime detects daylight savings automatically.

Answer (score 1):

**Here is the general algorithm:**

1. Pass your input to `mktime`.
2. Pass the output to `gmtime`.
3. Pass the output to `mktime`.

**And here is a coding example:**

```
struct tm  input  = Convert(input_string); // don't forget to set 'tm_isdst' here
time_t     temp1  = mktime(&input);
struct tm* temp2  = gmtime(&temp1);
time_t     output = mktime(temp2);
```

Note that function `gmtime` is **not** thread-safe, as it returns the address of a `static struct tm`.